# express nodejs socket.io LAMP

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, socket.io, lamp

I have back and front end running on LAMP environment accesible with `192.168.80.213/backend` `192.168.80.213/frontend`.

I try to make a push notification server using nodejs, socket.io and express framework to link back and front end.

Example : User order something from front end, i emit socket to my nodejs server from front end, then nodejs server emit to backend realtime notification 'hi you've got new order'

My nodejs server is listening on port `3000` while my backend and front end listenning on port 80 both using apache.

Here is my node client on backend :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/javascript/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io('http://192.168.80.213:3000/');
</script>
```

very simple isnt'it ?

Here is my node server :

```
const   express          = require('express')
        , app            = express()
        , http           = require('http').Server(app)
        , socketIo       = require('socket.io')(http)
        , cookieParser   = require('cookie-parser')
        , cookie         = require('cookie')
        , connect        = require('connect')
        , expressSession = require('express-session')
        , port           = 3000
        , helmet         = require('helmet')
        , name           = 'connect.sid'
        , sessionStore   = new expressSession.MemoryStore({ reapInterval: 60000 * 10 })
        , sessionSecret  = 'VH6cJa7yZSmkRbmjZW#J3%CDn%dt'
        , environment    = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
        ;

/** Configuration **/
app.enable('trust proxy');
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
    'name'  : name,
    'secret': sessionSecret,
    'store' : sessionStore,
    'resave': true,
    'saveUninitialized': true
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello from node');
});

socketIo.use(function(socket, callback) {
    // Read cookies from handshake headers
    var cookies = cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie);
    // We're now able to retrieve session ID
    var sessionID;
    if (cookies[name]) {
        console.log( "cookies['" + name + "'] = " + cookies[name] );
        sessionID = cookieParser.signedCookie( cookies[name], sessionSecret );
        console.log( "sessionID = " + sessionID );
    }else{
        console.log( "cookies['" + name + "'] = undefined" );
    }

    if (!sessionID) {
        console.log('ERROR NO SESSION CONNECTION REFUSED !!');
        callback('No session', false);
    } else {
        // Store session ID in handshake data, we'll use it later to associate
        // session with open sockets
        socket.handshake.sessionID = sessionID;
        callback(null, true);
    }

});


socketIo.on('connection', function (socket) { // New client
    console.log( 'new connection..' );
    console.log('user ' + socket.handshake.sessionID + ' authenticated and is now connected.');  

});

/** Start server */
http.listen(port);
console.log( "listening on :" + port );
```

Go to `192.168.80.213:3000` and see 'Hello from node' and cookie['connect.sid'] is set according to screenshot below

[image: connect.sid cookie correctly set]

And console output :

[image]

Now Clearing cache and i'm going to my back end app where is my nodeClient `192.168.80.213/backend`.

connect.sid cookie doesn't exist

[image]

And console output :

[image]

Why express-session won't set cookie.sid ? how can i fix that ? I'm new to node and express, i spend many times googling without succes, hope some node masters coul help me !!

regards

**EDIT 1**

i added this on my apache conf

```
ProxyPass /node http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse /node http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

So i can access to my node logic with 192.168.80.213/node

But now on my client side i got error :

```
var socket = io('http://192.168.80.213/node');
```

`192.168.80.213/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LeehEkF 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: I saw that io path option could be the trick. What value should i set for path ?!

Answer (score 0):

I think its because its on a different port.  What does your PHP program do?  It may be very easy to reproduce it in Node.  That way you would only need one program and one port.

Or you may be able to use something like Apache or nginx configuration to make the port go away in the URL with a reverse proxy or something so that the browser will keep the cookie.

Comment: I could do the same program only with node but i do not have enough time for that and it's a **big** PHP program. I tried something with apache but my nodeclient doesn't work anymore and return a 404 error :( maybe you have some config to provide me @JasonLivesay ?

Answer (score 0):

var socket = io('http://192.168.80.213/', { path: 'node'});

Or

var socket = io('http://192.168.80.213', { path: '/node'});
Try this